# Find out how many users are using my app

Tags: android

Is there a way to count how many users currently installed my app on their phone , then show the result for example in a text View ?

Comment: Use some analytics plugin like google analytics.

Comment: Install some analytics library or have you tried to write a user tracking service that you'd like to [edit] and show?

Comment: It's just an idea for now , i didn't know where to start , but i think i'm going to read some article about how to use this libraries

Comment: Firebase analytics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15522959/1638739) there is an open source called [Andlytics Project](https://github.com/AndlyticsProject/andlytics) which will enable you to reach your goal, also you can view this library called [segment](https://segment.com/docs/sources/mobile/android/) which as they said it enables you to :

> Collect customer data with one API and send it to hundreds of tools
>   for analytics, marketing, and data warehousing.

Comment: Thanks for the Reply mate

Comment: you are welcome, if this answer helps you kindly upvote it, and if it answers your problem kindly accept it.